# How to get firebase token and uid from OOBCODE?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are sending firebase email verification link to user.
After clicking on that, we have created custom page to verify the user.

All is working fine till now.

Now, after verify email, we are in logged out mode and we want to call the custom API with firebase ID and token.

We have OOBCODE in url, So can we get the firebase uid and token using OOBCODE?

> Below is the code:

```
if(router.query.oobCode)
{
  firebase.auth().applyActionCode(router.query.oobCode)
  .then((res) => {
    setValidCode(true)
    setVerifiedCode(true)
  }, 
  error => 
  {
    setError(error.message)
    setValidCode(false)
    setVerifiedCode(true)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `applyActionCode()` method only confirms that the email was successfully verified, nothing else. It just confirms that the verification email that was sent to the email address was opened, confirming that the email owner is the correct user. In particular, it doesn't log in the user to your app.

From there, it's up to you to implement the desired flow. You can redirect to a login page. You could also use the `apiKey` query string parameter that is present in the URL: it is the Firebase project's API key.

Comment: Same question but totally different flow: can I get the user UID by using the oobCode+apiKey in a specific http request? If so what would be the endpoint?

Comment: No you can't. The oobCode code is "a one-time code, used to identify and verify a request" and you can't link it back to the user uid or email. You will need to implement your own email verification system, it's not very complex. You can use the [Trigger Email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email).